# Angularfire Appcheck not initialized correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-app-check

I am using the angular fire 7.3 (modular) and is really unclear how to setup Appcheck. I am gettin a "*Missing or insufficient permissions.*" error and as I immagined Appcheck is blocking all calls for storage and firestore.

I have seen the code sample [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/app/app-check/app-check.component.ts)
and have configure the enviroment variables like shown [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/environments/environment.ts)
I have configured the app module similarly to how they suggested to do [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/app/app.module.ts), except that I am not using emulators

but it still acts as if the initialization didn't go through for what concerns Appcheck, both locally and on the deployed version. (both localhost and the domain have been regisred on recaptcha)

Obviously the recaptcha V3 site key I used is correct and has been setup on firebase as well. I did it before on a previous React project which at least for that part worked similarly but at least requests were going through.

...What am I missing?

I saw there is a post showing to essentially initialize firebase like you would do without angularfire but this would end up in having 2 firebase apps running and this sounds really hacky and suboptimal.

I wish their documentation said something about Appcheck...

app-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './components/layout/layout.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import { HeroComponent } from './components/hero/hero.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './components/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAnalytics,getAnalytics,ScreenTrackingService,UserTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { provideAuth,getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions,getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { provideStorage,getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AppcheckComponent } from './components/appcheck/appcheck.component';
import { ReleaseComponent } from './components/release/release.component';
import { PreloadComponent } from './components/preload/preload.component';

let resolvePersistenceEnabled: (enabled: boolean) => void;

export const persistenceEnabled = new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
  resolvePersistenceEnabled = resolve;
});


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    HeroComponent,
    PagenotfoundComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AppcheckComponent,
    ReleaseComponent,
    PreloadComponent,



  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),

  ],
  providers: [
    ScreenTrackingService,UserTrackingService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

appcheck-component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { getToken, AppCheck } from '@angular/fire/app-check';
import { traceUntilFirst } from '@angular/fire/performance';
import { EMPTY, from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { keepUnstableUntilFirst } from '@angular/fire';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-check',
  template: `
    <p>
      App Check!
      <code>{{ (change$ | async)?.token | slice:0:12 }}<ng-container *ngIf="(change$ | async) !== null">&hellip;</ng-container></code>
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})

export class AppcheckComponent implements OnInit {

  readonly change$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(appCheck: AppCheck) {
    if (appCheck) {
      this.change$ = from(getToken(appCheck)).pipe(
        traceUntilFirst('app-check'),
        keepUnstableUntilFirst,
        share(),
      );
    } else {
      this.change$ = EMPTY;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

enviroment variables

```
export const environment = {
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  },
  recaptcha3SiteKey: '...',
  production: false
};
```

Version Info:

Anglular 13.1
Firebase 9.8
AngularFire 7.3 (modular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the AppCheck provider to AppModule imports as you did with all the other ones (Firestore, Functions, etc).

```
import { initializeAppCheck, provideAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider } from '@angular/fire/app-check'    

... 

provideAppCheck(() =>
  initializeAppCheck(undefined, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(environment.recaptchaSiteKey),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
  })
),
```

Comment: Excellent! Now that you point it out it totally makes sense, so weird this was never implemented in the angularfire samples! Thank you very much!

Comment: @PleaseDontHurtMe you're quite welcome! Glad it worked. Could you accept the answer?

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so long. I upvoted it but forgot to accept, thanks again!